# Tomcat Error - Grails App - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: tomcat, grails, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

```
2011-06-17 09:11:45,277 [main] ERROR com].[/]  - Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps;   
nested exception     is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testProject.Checkin
```

I'm just trying to "new up" a normal Domain class in Grails. Never ran into this before (well I am new to this) I moved the "new" to the BootStrap.groovy just to see if it had something to do with the Controller causing same issue. Nope. Seems like the whole jar unaware of the testProject.Checkin class.
Saw somewhere to try Xverify:none as a Tomcat setting. Where would I set this?
What else should I do to troubleshoot the issue?

I am using the latest version of Tomcat 7.0.14

Comment: did you try a grails clean before creating the war?

Comment: also try to post your code! I would say that maybe u can have some wrong import, somewhere?!

Comment: hvgotcodes, great tip! Thought I was doing that on a regular basis. Now why did that work? I could understand how a class def might be out of date but how do they end up missing from not cleaning? Oh, and this would make a really good answer for me to select. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was a solution presented in the comments above wrt your actual problem but the question you posted regarding how to passing vm args to Tomcat is worth and answer too.

Since grails 1.3.5 you can explicitly pass jvm args to Tomcat when doing

```
$ grails run-war
```

to do so, add the following in your Config.groovy file

```
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ["-Xverify:none", "-Xmx1024m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"]
```

If you are simply running grails run-app then whatever jvm args that are being past to grails will be included in the running tomcat instance since the instance lives within the same JVM.

http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-war.html

Comment: Would this method also pass them to Tomcat when you have just grails prod war and then deployed it? How do those get passed after the JVM starts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the basics?

Run 'grails' war', see if your class compiled and is inside the war?

Does it work from grails run-app, but not the tomcat?

What environment are you working in?  SpringSource ToolSuite (STS) now provides a Grails "run on server" option for servers managed by Eclipse (i.e. Tomcat), and can help you get the environment up and running quickly.

Note that Grails 1.3.x ships with Tomcat 6.0.x, the latest 1.4M1 milestone release supports Tomcat7, so you may want to try that.